# Error in protobuf | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE :: while setting Sawtooth JavaScript Transaction Processor in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, docker-compose, hyperledger-sawtooth

Currently working on sawtooth [example](https://github.com/askmish/sawtooth-simplewallet)

Things I have done :

- Installed latest Node(8.11.3)& npm version.
- Started javascript

  - essential thing using docker-compose up.

Things giving error:

Want to setup **Javascript transaction processor** so moved to dir jsprocessor.

Trying to install all node modules using `$ npm i`, but giving error shown in image. I think it is relate to node js.

Reinstalled Node & NPM, Externally installed npm module that producing error but no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow the directions at
https://github.com/askmish/sawtooth-simplewallet
Which seems different from what you ran.

1. Build and start the Docker containers:
   docker-compose -f simplewallet-build-client-js.yaml up
2. Open bash shell in simplewallet-client-js container:
   docker exec -it simplewallet-client-js bash
3. Create user accounts for jack and jill:
   sawtooth keygen jack && sawtooth keygen jill
4. Open two new browser tabs and go to http://localhost:3000 on each tab.
   Login in one tab as jack and in other as jill Start with an initial deposit for each user - jack and jill via the Deposit tab in the UI homepage